# C++/CLI and GetLastError

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli

I have created a C++ Test Project for my C++ library in Visual Studio 2010. The test project uses C++/CLI (/clr set) and I am having problems retrieving the last error set by my library functions; GetLastError always returns zero.

In the example below I want to test that the correct return value and last error is set by my Write function:

```
[TestMethod]
void Write_InvalidHandle_Error()
{
    char buffer[] = "Hello";
    DWORD actual = -1;
    DWORD expected = ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE;
    int actualRetVal = 0;
    int expectedRetVal = -1;
    HANDLE handle = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

    actualRetVal = Write(handle, buffer);
    actual = GetLastError();
    Assert::AreEqual(expectedRetVal, actualRetVal);
    Assert::AreEqual(expected, actual);
}
```

I have checked my Write function and it does set the correct return value and last error but the latter is not retrieved in my test method. Even when I change the Write function to just set the error and return the problem occurs (and I call no other function before calling GetLastError in my test method):

```
int Write(HANDLE h, const char* buf)
{
    SetLastError(ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE);
    return -1;
}
```

Any idea how I can fix this? I assume there is a problem with C++/CLI because when I use my library outside of this testing scenario (pure C++) GetLastError works.

Comment: Can you provide the source code of the Write function?

Comment: @LukasT I added the simplest implementation possible that still produces the problem. I Think the problem has to do with C++/CLI because my code works when I don't involve it (i.e not running the test project).

Comment: So it boils down to the situation where you call SetLastError(VAL) and GetLastError returns 0 in c++-cli environment?

Comment: Yes, because it works when not using the testing project.

Answer (score 2):

Relying on GetLastError()/SetLastError() across the managed/unmanaged boundary is problematic.

When using P/Invoke and the [DllImport attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.dllimportattribute.aspx) you can (must) set the `SetLastError` property to get access to the native error code on the managed side.

When using C++/CLI, however, the compiler handles all marshalling for you, and explicitly does not set that flag.

You can read some more details about it in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adam_nathan/archive/2003/04/25/56643.aspx). The gist of it is:

> If you use DllImport explicitly in C++, the same rules apply as with
>   C#.  But when you call unmanaged APIs directly from managed C++ code,
>   neither GetLastError nor Marshal.GetLastWin32Error will work reliably.

This is also covered at length in Chapter 9 of "Expert Visual C++/CLI" by Marcus Heege which [is available on Google Books](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=wZoQyVi5f60C):

> As mentioned before, for these native local functions, C++/CLI
>   automatically generates P/Invoke metadata without the lasterror flag,
>   because it is very uncommon to use the GetLastError value to
>   communicate error codes within a project. However, the MSDN
>   documentation on GetLastError allows you to use SetLastError and
>   GetLastError for your own functions. Therefore, this  optimization can
>   theoretically cause wrong GetLastError values.

Basically, don't do it!

I would recommend to use (native) C++ exceptions to communicate errors between managed and unmanaged code. C++/CLI supports these very nicely. If you can't modify your `Write()` function directly, you could create a wrapper function on the unmanaged side which uses `GetLastError()` and then throws an exception if necessary.

Comment: My library never comes in contact with C++/CLI during normal usage, it's only when I want to run my unit tests because that's how the C++ test Project in Visual Studio 2010 works. I don't really want to change anything in my library but at least I know what my options are now. Thanks